# Windows 10 C++ NetworkExplorerPlugins context menu handler example

Tags: c++, windows, menu, handler

I have numerous ESP8266 / ESP32 / STM32 IOT devices, running my own firmware. One of the functions is a uPNP/SSDP provider which allows remote control from Amazon Echo devices and/or anything that can "speak" SSDP. I managed to find enough info to get these devices automatically added to the Windows network "Home Automation" view by tweaking the registry: [image]
My next step is to have what I *think* is a "context menu handler" so I can right-click the relevant device and have on/off/toggle options that then send the relevant SOAP envelop to the device to switch on etc. I'd also like to either change the icon (or add an overlay) in-flight to show the on/off state of the device, but that is icing on the cake.

I am having having serious difficulty finding an example C++ framework I can cut and paste to start me off that is relevant, accurate and modern. Every example I find is either for an explorer file menu, or in C#, or literally decades out of date: no doubt much is similar but it is "hooking" the thing in to the Network Pane of Windows 10 that I simply can't find how to do. Even on the MS developer site the information talks mostly about Vista and even XP(!) and is generally quite incomprehensible. The clearest site I could find (dated 2018) recommended a book on Windows Shell programming that was published in...wait for it...1998!

I know I'm going to have to build a DLL - I'm fine with that, I just need a good "leg-up".

"NetworkExplorerPlugins" brings up precisely 0 hits here.

I have been searching unsuccessfully for *weeks* - can anybody point me to a *recent* Windows 10-specific C++ example or tutorial that will get me started?